# Controlling playback quality using JS

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to control the playback quality of a video using Javascript?
To be more precise I want to select video quality using JavaScript..
Like I want automatically run youtube or any other video in 1080p instead of starting from 480/720P whenever I load the browser, either in chrome or firefox?

I am more into html/css and got no idea how to use JS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `&vq=hd1080` parameter to your youtube link

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/IqMLfrs1qm4&vq=hd1080" 
    title="YouTube video player" 
    frameborder="0" 
    allow="accelerometer; 
    autoplay; clipboard-write;    
    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I used this and found working for youtube..

Can you guide me how to do the same for a custom video which has a different kind of player (like vimeo/ amazon prime or something else)

Comment: Nice! 
As for other platforms, I think you should try and research it yourself because it only depends on the website. I only had to deal with this for YouTube videos 
For example, YouTube itself takes the value from the query parameter and sets the quality.